# Google Sitemap Submit show me an Error 404

Tags: sitemap

I have submited sitemap on Google Sitemap. When I check Submited and Indexed It shows large difference.

then I have check Errors in one File. that is as following.

```
General HTTP error: 404 not found
HTTP Error: 404
```

I have checked Error Guideline for 404. It shows me when File does not exist then this error will occur. but When I click on link of the file It is downloading the file. means file is exist.

I have tried to Re-Submit the file and check after another day but still It is showing same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re Submited the site map and the error is corrected now.